# PHP exec a unit testing with memory usage information

Tags: java, php, linux, testing, junit

I have a question relates to PHP and Java programming.
I am going to develop a web application to do a unit testing.
PHP is the language that I'll use for the web and will executes the exec() function.
as I read, the function returns the output of execution, ok I do need it.
but it's not enough, I also think if I can get how much memory are used during the execution.
the web will run in an Apache web server in a Linux native operating system (orefered in Ubuntu).

This is the second case:
if there is a Java source which contains a program in which requires the user input during the execution, how can I execute it via a web server with also pass all the lines which may act as the user input?

the next problem is, the exec() function only accepts parameters in line.
How if I want

so, if there is any idea how to do that things?

Comment: im not sure what you are asking but there is various profilers available for PHP that can give memory consumption. If you just want to know the memory usage or execution time of your unit-tests, then PHPUnit will give you that information by default after the test results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/usr/bin/time` program (documented in `time(1)`) can return the amount of memory used during execution:

```
$ /usr/bin/time echo hello
hello
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed ?%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 2512maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+205minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

You can see that the `echo(1)` program required 2.5 megabytes of memory and ran very quickly. Larger programs will be more impressive:

```
$ /usr/bin/time jacksum --help
Unknown argument. Use -h for help. Exit.
Command exited with non-zero status 2
0.08user 0.03system 0:00.87elapsed 12%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 57456maxresident)k
25608inputs+64outputs (92major+4072minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

`jacksum` is a Java-based program, so it took 57 megabytes to tell me I screwed up the command line arguments. That's more like it.

You might also find the BSD process account system worthwhile. See `lastcomm(1)`, `sa(8)`, and `dump-acct(8)` for more information.